# Problema hibernate size: 0 index:0

Tags: java, hibernate

Aquí es el método donde me tira la excepción, aparentemente no me devuelve nada en la lista, pero en la tabla de mysql veo como el cliente existe.

```
    public int returnidCliente(String param) {
    int idCliente = 0;
    List<Clientes> obj = new ArrayList<Clientes>();
    Query query = factorySession.createQuery("from Clientes e WHERE e.dni 
    =:dni");
    obj = query.setString("dni", param).list();
    objClientes = obj.get(0);
    idCliente = objClientes.getIdCliente();
    return idCliente;

  }
```

La clase clientes con todas las entidades

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clientes")
public class Clientes implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id_cliente")
private int idCliente;

@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "apellidos")
private String apellidos;

@Column(name = "dni")
private String dni;

@Column(name = "calles")
private String calles;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

public Clientes() {
}

public Clientes(String nombre, String apellidos, String dni, String calles, 
 String email{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.calles = calles;
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

la excepcion es `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

Supervisando con el debugger veo que el objeto cliente se rellena pero no entiendo por que me sale esa excepción cuando ejecuto la aplicación de forma normal, es decir con el debugger siguiente paso a paso todo marcha normal.

Comment: Intenta añadir detalles a la pregunta, puedes [edit] y añadir más información que nos ayude a ayudarte. Por ejemplo ¿Qué excepción te sale?. Te recomiendo además que completes el [tour] para entender qué tipo de preguntas se consideran *buenas* y por qué. Saludos y bienvenido

Comment: No veo tu método `getIdCliente()` ¿Podrías mostrarlo? ¿O esa es tu clase completa?

Comment: los setters y getter los he quitado por que si no me pide explicación en el problema

Comment: pero para acceder a la base de datos no deberías abrir sesion e iniciar transacción ?

Comment: tengo una session creada , esta en el constructor de la clase , me salta también esta excepcion com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe ser así:

```
Query queryCveLetra = session.createQuery("from Clientes e WHERE e.dni=:dni");
queryCveLetra.setString("dni",param );
```

Esto es si esperas que el hql te de solo 1 registro como resultado, que me parece lo mas probable por lo del dni:

```
Clientes cliente=(Clientes)queryCveLetra.uniqueResult();
idCliente = cliente.getIdCliente();
```

Esto es si esperas que el hql te conteste mas de 1 registro:

```
List<Clientes> obj=query.list();
for (Iterator<Clientes> iterator = obj.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Clientes cliente = (Clientes) iterator.next();
    idCliente = cliente.getIdCliente();
}
```